# From javascript call play 2.1 controller function that returns json data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to make play 2.1 controller function execute a captured external url and return json data object to javascript.

1. First of all InputStream is not opening an external url. errors out saying no protocol
2. play doesn't like  JSONObject as return.

code underway -

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/documents/getjsontext/" + talksUrl ,
        type: 'GET',
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){ do_this(data);},
        error: function () {alert("Error in Ajax Call");}
    });
```

Route- /documents/acontext/:jsonurl  controllers.Class.acontext(jsonurl: String)

```
public static JSONObject acontext(String jsonurl) {

    InputStream is = new URL(jsonurl).openStream();

    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "play 2.1 controller function"? Are you talking about http://www.playframework.com/? Maybe you want to do an Ajax request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Comment: yes Play framework 2.1

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to add a JsRoutes class. i named it as "myJsRoutes"

```
public class CommonController extends Controller{

    public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
        response().setContentType("text/javascript");
        return ok(
            Routes.javascriptRouter("myJsRoutes",
                routes.javascript.Controller_name.function()
                    );
      }
}
```

now your js route is defined .and "myJsRoutes" can be further used to call in your scala file as :

```
myJsRoutes.controllers.Controller_name.function_name().ajax({
 //your ajax handlers here
});
```